# Nvidia X Server -automatically enable GPU Fan Settings

Tags: nvidia, xserver

Unfortunately for Linux users there is no equivalent to the wonderful MSI Afterburner app for controlling your GPU fan.

The only alternative I know of is coolbits + the Nvidia X Server Settings application.

Unfortunately you have to manually enable and disable the GPU Fan Settings every time you want to lower your GPU temps under load.

Anyone know of a way to automate this?